Clion / Gdb - Debugging Using Docker Toolchain - Input/output error.- ARM - x86 Binaries
I am having lots of trouble debugging x86 binaries on my macOS using Docker in CLion. CLion is just my IDE of course; this issue can be reproduced just by using any debugger in Docker.
Here are the steps to reproduce the issue:

Compile your files using your Docker toolchain.
Try to debug the binary.
You will get the following error:

I understand that the issue comes from Apple Silicon, but I found these pages that discuss similar issues:

JetBrains YouTrack
GitHub microsoft/vscode-cpptools
GitHub orbstack
GitHub docker/for-mac

I am having lots of trouble understanding how to enable this Rosetta debug server. If anyone has done this in the past and could help out here, it would be lovely!
